# How To Match Password In RootViewController Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I am doing a task in which the password is set in the application Then the Password ViewController Set  In the Root , when I set up the password and after Some Time  open the app, the password View controller is open if password does not set  then open login page.

My work was almost completed but at the end of the work, I was confused about matching passwords How To match Password Because i am Using Same View Controller To Enter Password And Match Password.

This is my code for Set password:

```
let AllText = TF1.text! + TF2.text! + TF3.text! + TF4.text!
DBManager.sharedDatabase().insertRecord("INSERT INTO AppPassword (UserId,AppPassword) VALUES ('\(userId)','\(AllText)')")
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isValidLogin")  
AlertWithTimer(Alert: "Success", string: "Done \n You have Set password ")
```

This is code for set ViewController in Root in app delegate:

```
 func  setRootVC() {
    let storyboard =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if  UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isValidLogin") {
        let tabbarcontoller  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SetPassword")
        self.window?.rootViewController = tabbarcontoller
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    } else {
        let navVC =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navVC") as! UINavigationController
        let login = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginUser")
        navVC.setViewControllers([login], animated: false)
        self.window?.rootViewController = navVC
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to redefine the function in the else statement?

Comment: What do you mean by matching passwords?

Comment: Check Please Because else statement different identifier Login and in if statement which Password view controller @Scriptable

Comment: @Andy match Password means When i am set password In the application then how to match in root with same view controller

Comment: Any One Answer Please ???????????????

Comment: Can you clarify the problem? In `Set Password` you are setting `isValidLogin` to `true` so in `setRootVC` it will only go for the first time to `SetPassword` then it will always go to `LoginUser`. So where is the match thing?

Comment: Sir IsvalidLogin Is Key For Save Value In UserDefault For Check in This key Contain Value or Not if contain then go Password view Controller Other Wise Login Screen....

Comment: Any One Answer Please ???????????????